# Somando uma lista de compra - Java

Tags: java

Nesse código preciso somar toda as compras feitas sem usar laços, com o stream ou de forma recursiva. Tentei usar o reduce para realizar essa soma, porém senti dificuldade no sentido de multiplicar o valor pela quantidade de itens e então encontrar o valor final.

```java
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class DesafioSemLoop {
  public static BigDecimal totalCompras(List<Compra> compras) {
    return BigDecimal.ZERO;
  }

  // a partir daqui não pode mudar nada
  public static void main(String... args) {
    List<Compra> compras = Arrays.asList(
      new Compra(
        "2022-01-01",
        Arrays.asList(
          new ItemCompra("a", 2, new BigDecimal("12.34")), // 24.68
          new ItemCompra("b", 1, new BigDecimal("3.99")),
          new ItemCompra("d", 3, new BigDecimal("98.14")) // 294.42
        )
      ),
      new Compra(
        "2022-01-02",
        Arrays.asList(
          new ItemCompra("a", 6, new BigDecimal("12.34")), // 74.04
          new ItemCompra("b", 1, new BigDecimal("3.99")),
          new ItemCompra("c", 1, new BigDecimal("34.02"))
        )
      )
    );

    System.out.println("O total das compras foi de " + totalCompras(compras).toPlainString());
  }

  public static class Compra {
    public final String data;
    public final List<ItemCompra> produtos;

    public Compra(String data, List<ItemCompra> produtos) {
      this.data = data;
      this.produtos = Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(produtos));
    }
  }

  public static class ItemCompra {
    public final String cod;
    public final int qtd;
    public final BigDecimal valorUnitario;

    public ItemCompra(String cod, int qtd, BigDecimal valorUnitario) {
      this.cod = cod;
      this.qtd = qtd;
      this.valorUnitario = valorUnitario;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro a gente transforma a stream de `Compra` em uma stream de `ItemCompra` usando o método `flatMap`. Porque são os itens que nos interessam já que são eles que tem as informações relevantes.

```java
Stream<ItemCompra> itens =
  compras.stream().flatMap(compra -> compra.produtos.stream());
```

Em seguida, usamos o método `map` para retornar o valor de cada compra já multiplicado pela quantidade.

```java
Stream<BigDecimal> valoresMultiplicados =
  itens.map(item -> item.valorUnitario.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(item.qtd)));
```

Por último usamos o método `reduce` para retornar a soma de todos os valores.

```java
return valoresMultiplicados.reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

O método completo ficaria assim:

```java
public static BigDecimal totalCompras(List<Compra> compras) {
  Stream<ItemCompra> itens =
    compras.stream().flatMap(compra -> compra.produtos.stream());

  Stream<BigDecimal> valoresMultiplicados =
    itens.map(item -> item.valorUnitario.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(item.qtd)));

  return valoresMultiplicados.reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
}
```

Mas vc pode encadear tudo para ficar mais elegante.

```java
public static BigDecimal totalCompras(List<Compra> compras) {
  return compras
    .stream()
    .flatMap(compra -> compra.produtos.stream())
    .map(item -> item.valorUnitario.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(item.qtd)))
    .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela contribuição havia feito com a ajuda de um amigo, onde ficou bem parecido.
 `public static BigDecimal totalCompras(List<Compra> compras) {
         return compras.stream()
                .map((c)-> c.produtos)
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .map((item) -> BigDecimal.valueOf(item.qtd).multiply(item.valorUnitario))
                .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, (Acumulador, ValorAtual) -> Acumulador.add(ValorAtual) );
    }`